# unresolved dependencies error in android studios.First time user of android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, build.gradle

I installed Android Studio for the first time and created a new project and soon after I created the project I got build error: Unresolved Dependencies and Run Task error:

> Unable to resolve dependency for `':app@debug/compileClasspath'`: Could
>   not find any version that matches
>   com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for `':app@debug/compileClasspath':` Could
>   not find any version that matches com.android.support:design:29.+.
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for
>   `':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath'`: Could not find any version
>   that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for
>   `':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath'`: Could not find any version
>   that matches com.android.support:design:29.+.
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for
>   `':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath'`: Could not find any version that
>   matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for
>   `':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath':` Could not find any version that
>   matches com.android.support:design:29.+.
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for `':app@release/compileClasspath'`:
>   Could not find any version that matches
>   com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for `':app@release/compileClasspath'`:
>   Could not find any version that matches
>   com.android.support:design:29.+.
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for
>   `':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath'`: Could not find any version
>   that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for
>   `':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath'`: Could not find any version
>   that matches com.android.support:design:29.+.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you will have to disable/uncheck work offline option.

File->Other Settings->Default Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Build Tools->Gradle->UnCheck Work Offline.